# Linear algebra, reduced row echelon form - function 1

Tags: javascript, beginner, mathematics, matrix

This is a derivative post from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54539/linear-algebra-reduced-row-echelon-form).

This is just a general review, so the question is the same:

Is there something...

1. That you would consider as a bad practice and why?
2. That is just bad in some other way?

This question applies to the function `toRowEchelonForm(matrix, returnMethod)`.

(Just to be clear, this is not a production code. There are too few tests and I do not guarantee it does what it is supposed to do. WolframAlpha limits its inputs and I haven't found alternative yet.)

```
/*jslint browser: true, indent: 8 */
/*global console */

function toRowEchelonForm(matrix, returnMethod) {
        'use strict';
        var f, pivotRow, toReduceRow, scaledRow, len, pos, new_matrix;

        function sortRows(matrix) {
                var pivots, c;
                // map rows to arrays with the structure
                // [<column index>, <pivot coefficient>, <row index>]
                // which makes them easily sortable
                pivots = matrix.map(function (row, r) {
                        var len = row.length;

                        for (c = 0; c < len; c += 1) {
                                if (row[c]) {
                                        return [c, row[c], r]; // found a non-zero coefficient at matrix[r][c]
                                }
                        }

                        return [Infinity, null, r]; // row is all-zero
                });

                // sort the pivots array, and use it to (re)build
                // the matrix with the rows in the correct order
                return pivots.sort().map(function (pivot) {
                        return matrix[pivot[2]];
                });
        }

        function leadingPivotsToTop(matrix) {
                var r, c, len, has_pivot, irrelevant, positions, new_matrix, count;

                len = {
                        row: matrix.length,
                        col: matrix[0].length
                };
                positions  = [];
                has_pivot  = [];
                irrelevant = [];
                new_matrix = [];
                count      = 0;

                // Find pivot positions
                for (c = 0; c < len.col; c += 1) {
                        for (r = 0; r < len.row; r += 1) {
                                if (matrix[r][c] === 1 && has_pivot[r] !== r) {
                                        has_pivot[r] = r;
                                        positions[positions.length] = r;
                                        break;
                                }
                        }
                }

                // Find irrelevant vectors positions
                for (r = 0; r < len.row; r += 1) {
                        if (has_pivot[r] === undefined) {
                                irrelevant[irrelevant.length] = r;
                                count += 1;
                        }
                }

                count = 0;

                // Sort positions
                for (r = 0; r < len.row; r += 1) {
                        if (matrix[positions[r]] !== undefined) {
                                new_matrix[r] = matrix[positions[r]];
                        } else {
                                new_matrix[r] = matrix[irrelevant[count]];
                                count += 1;
                        }
                }

                return new_matrix;
        }

        new_matrix = matrix;
        pos = {
                pivot: 0,
                reserved: []
        };
        len = {
                row: matrix.length,
                col: matrix[0].length
        };
        f = {
                getPivotPosition: function (pivotRow) {
                        var c;

                        for (c = 0; c < len.col; c += 1) {
                                if (new_matrix[pivotRow][c] !== 0
                                && pos.reserved[c] === undefined) {
                                        pos.reserved[c] = 1;
                                        return c;
                                }
                        }

                        return null;
                },
                reducePivotRow: function (pivotRow) {
                        var c, pivot;

                        if (new_matrix[pivotRow][pos.pivot] !== 1) {
                                pivot = new_matrix[pivotRow][pos.pivot];
                                for (c = 0; c < len.col; c += 1) {
                                        new_matrix[pivotRow][c] /= pivot;
                                }
                        }
                },
                scaleRow: function (pivotRow, toReduceRow) {
                        var c, row;

                        row = [];

                        for (c = 0; c < len.col; c += 1) {
                                row[c]  = new_matrix[pivotRow][c];
                                row[c] *= new_matrix[toReduceRow][pos.pivot];
                        }

                        return row;
                },
                rowReduction: function (toReduceRow, scaledRow) {
                        var c;

                        for (c = 0; c < len.col; c += 1) {
                                new_matrix[toReduceRow][c] -= scaledRow[c];
                        }
                }
        };

        for (pivotRow = 0; pivotRow < len.row; pivotRow += 1) {

                pos.pivot = null;

                pos.pivot = f.getPivotPosition(pivotRow);

                if (pos.pivot !== null) {
                        f.reducePivotRow(pivotRow);

                        for (
                                toReduceRow = 0;
                                toReduceRow < len.row;
                                toReduceRow += 1
                        ) {
                                if (toReduceRow !== pivotRow
                                && new_matrix[toReduceRow][pos.pivot] !== 0) {
                                        scaledRow = f.scaleRow(
                                                pivotRow,
                                                toReduceRow
                                        );
                                        f.rowReduction(
                                                toReduceRow,
                                                scaledRow
                                        );
                                }
                        }
                }
        }

        if (returnMethod === "raw") {
                return new_matrix;
        } else if (returnMethod === "lead to top") {
                return leadingPivotsToTop(new_matrix);
        } else if (returnMethod === "lead to top and zeroes to bottom") {
                return sortRows(new_matrix);
        } else {
                return leadingPivotsToTop(new_matrix);
        }
}

function compereMatrices(matrixA, matrixB) {
        'use strict';
        var i, j, len;

        if (matrixA.length !== matrixB.length) {
                return false;
        }

        len = {};

        len.i = matrixA.length;

        for (i = 0; i < len.i; i += 1) {
                if (matrixA[i].length !== matrixB[i].length) {
                        return false;
                }

                len.j = matrixA[i].length;

                for (j = 0; j < len.j; j += 1) {
                        if (matrixA[i][j] !== matrixB[i][j]) {
                                return false;
                        }
                }
        }

        return true;
}


// Tests.
var m = [
        [5, -7, -8, -4],
        [2, 8, -22, -55],
        [-3, 0, -36, 12]
];
// answer: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+row+echelon+form+{{5%2C+-7%2C+-8%2C+-4}%2C{2%2C+8%2C+-22%2C+-55}%2C+{-3%2C+0%2C+-36%2C+12}}
var mr = [
        [1, 0, 0, -6.785219399538105],
        [0, 1, 0, -4.54041570438799],
        [0, 0, 1, 0.23210161662817538]
];

console.log(" ");
console.log("toRowEcholonForm test:         " + compereMatrices(toRowEchelonForm(m), mr));

// answer: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+row+echelon+form+{{5%2C+-23%2C+2%2C+4%2C+5%2C+11}%2C{4%2C+-3%2C+6%2C+4%2C+5%2C+2}%2C{3%2C+7%2C+-18%2C+7%2C+9%2C+-6}%2C{4%2C+87%2C+-12%2C+7%2C+12%2C+6}%2C{5%2C+4%2C+7%2C+11%2C+7%2C+-7}}
var m = [
        [5, -23, 2, 4, 5, 11],
        [4, -3, 6, 4, 5, 2],
        [3, 7, -18, 7, 9, -6],
        [4, 87, -12, 7, 12, 6],
        [5, 4, 7, 11, 7, -7]
];

var mr = [
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10.784116921993304],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.3085998347488045],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1.0969699432456959],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1.369593780053366],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -5.630094680807834]
];

console.log(" ");
console.log("toRowEcholonForm test:         " + compereMatrices(toRowEchelonForm(m), mr));

// answer: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+row+echelon+form+{{1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2}%2C{1%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3}%2C+{1%2C+4%2C+16%2C+5}}
m = [
        [1, 2, 2, 2],
        [1, 3, 3, 3],
        [1, 4, 16, 5]
];

mr = [
        [1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0.9166666666666666],
        [0, 0, 1, 0.08333333333333333]
];

console.log(" ");
console.log("toRowEcholonForm test:         " + compereMatrices(toRowEchelonForm(m), mr));

// answer: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+row+echelon+form+{{0%2C+2%2C+-1%2C+-6}%2C{0%2C+3%2C+-2%2C+-16}%2C+{0%2C+0%2C+-3%2C+11}}
m = [
        [0, 2, -1, -6],
        [0, 3, -2, -16],
        [0, 0, -3, 11]
];

mr = [
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]
];

console.log(" ");
console.log("toRowEcholonForm test:         " + compereMatrices(toRowEchelonForm(m), mr));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot of meat here; I'll try to do it justice. I've focussed on the core reduction logic, and <strike>haven't looked at the "post-processing" stuff that sorts the reduced matrix</strike> update: I lied - see bottom of answer.

#### Minor stuff

- There are a few constructions like this:

  ```
  pos.pivot = null;
  pos.pivot = f.getPivotPosition(pivotRow);
  ```

  but since `f.getPivotPosition()` defaults to returning `null` anyway, the first line is irrelevant. Not a huge concern by any stretch, but it made me go "huh?"
- There are a few strict comparisons against `undefined`. While possible, I'd prefer explicitly setting a boolean value to compare against, or using type coercion. For one, [many browsers allow `undefined` to be *set to anything*](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Immutable_undefined), which can quickly break your code (the solution is to use `typeof x === 'undefined'`). But I'd also find it more straight-forward to read

  ```
  if(!pos.reserved[c])
  ```

  rather than

  ```
  if(pos.reserved[c] === undefined)
  ```

  because, semantically speaking, the condition being invoked is "if this position isn't reserved..." - not "if this position something we've never heard of...".
  Of course you want to be careful with type coercion, since zero is false'y - same as `undefined`, `null` or `false` itself - and you're working with indices that might well be zero. But in that case I'd explicitly set `false` or `null` (or -1, which is what `indexOf()` uses to mean "no index found"), and strictly check for *that*.

#### Bigger stuff

While you've extracted quite a few functions, they're very tied to an external state. You provide some of the values they need as arguments, but `scaleRow` (for instance), also relies on `pos.pivot`. So it's sort of "halfway extracted". It's not reusable, although the act of scaling a vector is actually a generic operation.

What you want is just to multiply every element in an array (aka row/vector) with a value, producing a new, scaled vector. Basically, \$\mathbf{V}\times c\$. You can achieve this like so:

```
 function scale(vector, factor) {
   // map returns a new array, produced by invoking the
   // iterator function on each element
   return vector.map(function (value) {
     return value * factor;
   });
 }
```

This function is completely independent, stateless and reusable. Of course, achieving these qualities isn't necessary for an inlined function (JS has closures for a reason: They're awesome!), but if you're going to *extract* a function, aim for maximum independence.

#### My take

I've left out the sorting functions, but this seems to work well. I've commented the code pretty heavily; hope it's clear

```
function reducedRowEchelonForm(matrix) {
  var knownPivotColumns = []; // this is our one piece of iffy state-keeping :(

  // Copy the input matrix (reusing the variable name) so we have a local copy to work on
  matrix = matrix.map(function (row) { return row.slice() });

  // Now, go through the matrix and do the reduction.
  // We're using forEach here, because we want to update the matrix
  // in-place, whereas `map()` will work on a separate instance
  matrix.forEach(function (row, rowIndex) {

    // Find the row's pivot
    // This is wrapped in an IIFE just for structure
    var pivot = (function () {
      // using a regular for-loop, since we may want to break out of it early
      for(var i = 0, l = row.length ; i < l ; i++ ) {
        if(!row[i] || knownPivotColumns[i]) { continue } // skip column if it's zero or its index is taken
        knownPivotColumns[i] = true;                     // "reserve" the column
        return { index: i, value: row[i] };              // return the pivot data
      }
      return null; // no pivot found
    }());

    // if there's no pivot, there's nothing else to do for this row
    if(!pivot) { return }

    // scale the row, if necessary
    if(pivot.value !== 1) {
      // using forEach as a "map in place" here
      row.forEach(function (_, i) { row[i] /= pivot.value });
    }

    // now reduce the other rows (calling them "siblings" here)
    matrix.forEach(function (sibling) {
      var siblingPivotValue = sibling[pivot.index];

      if(sibling === row || siblingPivotValue === 0) { return } // skip if possible

      // subtract the sibling-pivot-scaled row from the sibling
      // (another "forEach as map-in-place")
      sibling.forEach(function (_, i) { sibling[i] -= row[i] * siblingPivotValue });
    });
  });

  return matrix;
}
```

(jslint will complain about missing semi-colons,but I've only omitted them where it's "safe" - i.e. immediately before a `}`)

You'll note that I haven't actually extracted any functions here. Everything is inlined, and there's even an IIFE. This was mostly to keep things self-contained for the purposes of this answer. Ideally, one would have a little library of generic vector/matrix functions (like `scale()` above) which could handle a lot of this stuff. A generic `transform()` function that alters an array in-place might also be handy (an extraction of the `forEach`-use above).

As for the sorting/post-processing stuff, I'd leave that up to the user. Reducing the matrix is one operation. Sorting its rows is completely separate. So I'd prefer to write code like:

```
 var reduced = reducedRowEchelonForm(matrix);
 var sorted = sortRows(reduced);
```

rather than passing more arguments to the reduce function. The `sortRows()` function is a nice, generic function ([if I do say so myself](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/54563/14370)) that doesn't care where its input came from. It just sorts it. If you don't want to sort it, well, don't.

---

OK, one quick look at the `leadingPivotsToTop()` function:

Basically, you can achieve this (I think) by

1. dividing the rows into those that have a pivot and the irrelevant ones
2. sorting the ones with a pivot using the existing `sortRows`
3. gluing (concatenating) the irrelevant ones back on

Something like this (untested!)

```
function leadingPivotsToTop(matrix) {
  var pivotIndices = [],
      pivotedRows = [],
      irrelevantRows = [];

  matrix.forEach(function (row) {
    var pivotIndex = row.findIndex(function (value) { return value === 1 });
    if(pivotIndex === -1 || pivotIndices[pivotIndex]) {
      irrelevantRows.push(row);
    } else {
      pivotIndices[pivotIndex] = true;
      pivotedRows.push(row);
    }
  });

  return sortRows(pivotedRows).concat(irrelevantRows);
}
```

Note that [`findIndex()` isn't widely supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), but it's easy enough to roll your own - or just find a working one. The linked MDN page has an implementation you can borrow.

Comment: Thank you for your review! One question, do you know if "map" method optimized by some JavaScript uglifier out there? If not then I am thinking about to write a parser for that purposes :-)

Comment: @user1235831 You can see the reason why your edit was rejected in your user profile. It would be informative for you. You should have had a comment on this answer instead of editing directly. If you have a question of want more information you can visit the [meta].

Comment: @Marc-Andre Just saw the rejected edit(s). Thanks. (Turns out they were partly correct though)

Comment: @user1235831 What do you mean by "'map' method optimized by an uglifier"? Also: Saw your edits. You were right about the `pivot.index`/`pivot.column` confusion; fixed that. Thanks. But the `row === sibling` comparison remains unchanged; it works just fine, and is more direct than comparing the indices.

Comment: @Marc-Andre, thank you, I am still figuring all of this out...

Comment: @user1235831 No problem, using Stack Exchange in the beginning is not an easy thing!

Comment: I am going to make your answer as the accepted answer; I just want to make sure it works. I don't see the change yet but when I can confirm it works I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: About row === sibling, I can't reason why that would work, but it passes the tests. What is happening under the hood when these arrays are compared to each other directly?

Comment: To answer the question about: 'What do you mean by "'map' method optimized by an uglifier"?' JavaScript "Uglifiers" are similar to JavaScript "minifiers", but your code will be completely unreadable as it will compress variable and function names. "map" method seemed to have a price of execution speed, so it is natural to consider if it can be optimized. Normally, it shouldn't matter for simple websites, but I want to play with webgl :-)

Comment: @user1235831 JS is object oriented, and we're looping through the same array, so `row` and `sibling` are just object references. So, at a certain index, `row` is the exact same object as `sibling` and vice-versa; it's two names pointing at the same thing. You could also compare the indices of course, but what really we want to know is whether it's the same row. So instead of asking "is this number the same as that number?" we just ask "is this the same thing?"

Comment: @user1235831 A minifier/uglifier typically isn't a static analyzer; it just - as you say - shortens variable names and removes whitespace (Google's Closure Compiler is an exception; it'll actually optimize the code, not just the filesize). But `map` is a qualitatively different operation than a regular loop, so a call to `map` will remain a call to `map`. Sure, `map` iterates through an array much like a loop, but it's not the same procedure at all. Besides, `map` isn't a huge performance drain. It's a native function, so it's partly running as compiled code; not interpreted JS.

Comment: Now I get what is happening under the hood with row and sibling, nice insight btw! **map** is nice but I'm not really sure if it is good when you are working with something as expensive as matrices. Both **map** and **foreach** seem to require a callback and this seems to slow the loop down. They make the code a lot cleaner, but I don't think I am going to use them unless I can replace them with a parser later. This should be possible if there is "one to one" or "one to many correlation" between context and method. Anyway, I learned a lot from this! Again, thanks for the review! :-)